# How to use the ccf() method in the statsmodels library?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, cross-correlation

I am having some trouble with the `ccf()` method in the (Python) `statsmodels` library. The equivalent operation works fine in R.

`ccf` produces a cross-correlation function between two variables, `A` and `B` in my example. I am interested to understand the extent to which `A` is a leading indicator for `B`.

I am using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as smt
```

I can simulate `A` and `B` as follows:

```
np.random.seed(123)
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(79, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

When I run `ccf`, I get the following:

```
ccf_output = smt.ccf(test['A'],test['B'], unbiased=False)
ccf_output    
array([ 0.09447372, -0.12810284,  0.15581492, -0.05123683,  0.23403344,
    0.0771812 ,  0.01434263,  0.00986775, -0.23812752, -0.03996113,
   -0.14383829,  0.0178347 ,  0.23224969,  0.0829421 ,  0.14981321,
   -0.07094772, -0.17713121,  0.15377192, -0.19161986,  0.08006699,
   -0.01044449, -0.04913098,  0.06682942, -0.02087582,  0.06453489,
    0.01995989, -0.08961562,  0.02076603,  0.01085041, -0.01357792,
    0.17009109, -0.07586774, -0.0183845 , -0.0327533 , -0.19266634,
   -0.00433252, -0.00915397,  0.11568826, -0.02069836, -0.03110162,
    0.08500599,  0.01171839, -0.04837527,  0.10352341, -0.14512205,
   -0.00203772,  0.13876788, -0.20846099,  0.30174408, -0.05674962,
   -0.03824093,  0.04494932, -0.21788683,  0.00113469,  0.07381456,
   -0.04039815,  0.06661601, -0.04302084,  0.01624429, -0.00399155,
   -0.0359768 ,  0.10264208, -0.09216649,  0.06391548,  0.04904064,
   -0.05930197,  0.11127125, -0.06346119, -0.08973581,  0.06459495,
   -0.09600202,  0.02720553,  0.05152299, -0.0220437 ,  0.04818264,
   -0.02235086, -0.05485135, -0.01077366,  0.02566737])
```

Here is the outcome I am trying to get to (produced in R):

[image]

The problem is this: `ccf_output` is giving me only the correlation values for lag 0 and to the right of Lag 0.  Ideally, I would like the full set of lag values (lag -60 to lag 60) so that I can produce something like the above plot.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The statsmodels `ccf` function only produces forward lags, i.e. Corr(x_[t+k], y_[t]) for k >= 0. But one way to compute the backwards lags is by reversing the order of the both the input series and the output.

```
backwards = smt.ccf(test['A'][::-1], test['B'][::-1], adjusted=False)[::-1]
forwards = smt.ccf(test['A'], test['B'], adjusted=False)
ccf_output = np.r_[backwards[:-1], forwards]
```

Note that both `backwards` and `forwards` contained lag 0, so we had to remove that from one of them when combining them.

**Edit** another alternative is to reverse the order of the arguments and the output:

```
backwards = sm.tsa.ccf(test['B'], test['A'], adjusted=False)[::-1]
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Small note - I believe "adjusted" should be "unbiased".:

Comment: in other words . . . backwards = sm.tsa.ccf(test['B'], test['A'], unbiased = False)[::-1]

Comment: Good point. However, note that the `unbiased` argument will be deprecated in the upcoming v0.12 release of statsmodels in favor of the `adjusted` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The desired cross-correlation plot can be obtained as below (from which we can estimate the best lag for CCF by finding the peak):

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
#np.random.seed(123)
#test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(79, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
#backwards = smt.ccf(test['B'], test['A'], unbiased=False)[::-1]
#forwards = smt.ccf(test['A'], test['B'], unbiased=False)
#ccf_output = np.r_[backwards[:-1], forwards]
plt.stem(range(-len(ccf_output)//2, len(ccf_output)//2), ccf_output)
plt.xlabel('Lag')
plt.ylabel('ACF')
# 95% UCL / LCL
plt.axhline(-1.96/np.sqrt(len(test)), color='k', ls='--') 
plt.axhline(1.96/np.sqrt(len(test)), color='k', ls='--')
```

[image]

Comment: The best solution available all over the internet on this question!