# cross correlation plot in statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Consider the simple example below, borrowed from [How to use the ccf() method in the statsmodels library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63491991/how-to-use-the-ccf-method-in-the-statsmodels-library)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.tsa.stattools as smt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(79, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
```

I know how to create the `forward` and `backward` lags of the cross-correlation function (see SO link above) but the issue is how to obtain a proper dataframe containing the correct lag order. I came up with the solution below.

```
backwards = smt.ccf(test['A'][::-1], test['B'][::-1], adjusted=False)[::-1]

forwards = smt.ccf(test['A'], test['B'], adjusted=False)

#note how we skip the first lag (at 0) because we have a duplicate with the backward values otherwise
a = pd.DataFrame({'lag': range(1, len(forwards)),
              'value' : forwards[1:]})

b = pd.DataFrame({'lag':  [-i for i in list(range(0, len(forwards)))[::-1]],
              'value' : backwards})

full = pd.concat([a,b])
full.sort_values(by = 'lag', inplace = True)
full.set_index('lag').value.plot()
```

[image]

However, this seems to be a lot of code for something that that conceptually is very simple (just appending two lists). Can this code be streamlined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try "just appending to lists":

```
# also
# cc = list(backards) + list(forwards[1:])
cc = np.concatenate([backwards, forwards[1:]])
full = pd.DataFrame({'lag':np.arange(len(cc))-len(backwards), 
                     'value':cc})
full.plot(x='lag')
```

Also:

```
full = (pd.DataFrame({'value':np.concatenate([backwards, forwards[1:]])})
          .assign(lag=lambda x: x.index - len(backwards) )
       )
```

Output:

[image]

**Note** if all you want is to plot the two arrays, then this would do

```
plt.plot(-np.arange(len(backwards)), backwards, c='C0')
plt.plot(forwards, c='C0')
```

Comment: ah the `np.arange(len(cc))-len(backwards)` is a nice trick! well done!

Answer (score 0):

For Quang Hoang's answer, I suggest to use `np.arange(len(cc))-len(backwards)-1` because ccf returns the cross correlation coefficient starting from lag 0.